# Implicit dependency specified in target platform not resolved on launch

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

As part of a transition of a stand-alone application to the Eclipse RCP framework, 
I included a plugin (`plugin-core`) as part of the target platform and added it to the list of implicit dependencies in the target platform.

I then proceeded to create a UI feature wrapping a single UI plugin (for now) and defined a dependency to `plugin-core` in the UI plugin. I then included this feature in a product (the only feature in this product for now) and attempted to run the application.

However, I received an unresolved dependency error for the `plugin-core`. I thought that plugins that were included in the target platform and for which the implicit dependency was defined would be resolved without having to explicitly include them in a feature.

I was only able to resolve this problem by explicitly including `plugin-core` in my UI feature as well.

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you use must be listed in a feature, either one that you create or one of the existing Eclipse features that you include in the RCP. Eclipse will not include anything else when you build the RCP product.

Comment: What's the purpose of the implicit dependencies then? How does it help in anyway if those plugins need to be explicitly added to a feature for inclusion in an RCP...?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'implicit dependencies'. Do you mean Import-Package or something like that?

Comment: I'm referring to the option in setting up the target platform. See the following link: http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Ftarget_shared%2Fedit_target_implicit_tab.htm

Comment: That is just to force plugins in to dependency calculations, it doesn't remove the requirement to explicitly specify every plugin required in the product build.